# VueJS - How to import sub-components only once in parent component

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

Let's say I have an `App.vue` file with the following

```
<template>
    <task-list>
        <task>Task 1</task>
        <task>Task 2</task>
    </task-list>
</template>
<script>
import TaskList from './tasklist.vue'
export default {
    //...
    components: {
        TaskList
    }
    //...
}
</script>
```

a `TaskList.vue`

```
<template>
    <ul>
        <slot></slot>
    </ul>
</template>
<script>
import Task from './task.vue'
export default {
    //...
    name: 'task-list'
    components: {
        Task
    }
    //...
}
</script>
```

a `Task.vue`

```
<template>
    <li><slot></slot></li>
</template>
<script>
export default {
    name: 'task',
    //...
}
</script>
```

and a `main.js`

```
import App from './App.vue'

new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  render: h => h(App)
})
```

How do I import the sub-component `Task.vue` only once in `TaskList.vue` without also having to import it again in `App.vue`

It seems that if I do it this way, I get an error back from VueJS complaining about unregistered components

> [Vue warn]: Unknown custom element:  - did you register the
>   component correctly? For recursive components, make sure to provide
>   the "name" option.
>
> found in
>
> --->  at src/App.vue

Is there a way to indicate that `task` is a sub-component of `task-list` without global registration or importing again in `App.vue`?

Comment: Why don't you include the `Task` component inside the `TaskList` component template. This would make more sense. Or is there a specific reason why you choose not to do that?

Comment: @puelo I mean for other cases where I just want to have components nested inside eachother that are related, like how `li` is always a child of `ul`, I want to know if there's a way to say that this component is a sub-component of another so I can just import `tasks` in `App.vue` instead of `tasks` and `task`

Comment: The normal way would be to create a TaskList and define a property which can be passed down and then inside the TaskList you create the list (however the syntax might be) containing the task sub-components. I don't think you can import multiple components by just importing the parent (unsure). (TaskList example: https://jsfiddle.net/5xy17zs8/2/)

Answer (score 1):

If you register `Task` in `TaskList.vue`,

then you can only use `<task>` in `TaskList.vue`'s template.

---

Try this: `App.vue` use props to pass tasks (an array) to `TaskList.vue`

`App.vue`

```
<template>
    <task-list :tasks="tasks"></task-list>
</template>
<script>
import TaskList from "./tasklist.vue";
export default {
  //...
  data() {
    return {
      tasks: ['Task 1', 'Task 2']
    };
  },
  components: {
    TaskList
  },
  //...
};
</script>
```

`TaskList.vue`

```
<template>
  <ul>
    <task v-for="task in tasks" :key="task">{{ task }}</task>
  </ul>
</template>

<script>
import Task from './Task.vue';
export default {
  name: "task-list",
  props: {
    tasks: {
      type: Array,
      default: () => []
    }
  },
  components: {
    Task
  }
  //...
};
</script>
```

### Full example app:

[image: Edit Vue Template]

Answer (score 1):

add a custom component `task` in `App.vue`:

```
<template>
  <task-list>
    <task>Task 1</task>
    <task>Task 2</task>
  </task-list>
</template>

<script>
import TaskList from './tasklist.vue'
import Task from './Task.vue'

export default {
    //...
    components: {
        TaskList,
        Task
    }
    //...
}
</script>
```